# Make Mint forget share credentials

Tags: linux, mount, linux-mint, samba

I typically edit my `/etc/fstab` file when I want to mount a share, but I was in a hurry when installing a new OS and instead used the GUI to mount a samba share and I selected the "Remember forever" option.

I want the credentials I entered to be forgotten, but no amount of unmounting is doing the trick.

I'm running Mint 17 Cinnamon.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your passwords are stored in `~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring`, which is a keyring by [**GNOME Keyring**](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring).  To edit items in this file, use [**Seahorse**](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Seahorse).

To install Seahorse, run this command:

```
sudo apt install seahorse
```

Seahorse looks like this:

[image: You should not see this text. This text should be a screenshot of Seahorse.]

You can delete items by right-mouse clicking them and then clicking on "Delete".

---

<sup><sub>**More information:** ["Where are passwords saved?" on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/139337/18979)</sub></sup>